# f.write (python) escreve "None" no arquivo

Tags: python, python-3.x, arquivo

Olá, eu sou iniciante e estou tentando criar um programa que gere um arquivo de texto, mas cada linha sendo aleatória (com base em frase pré-definida).

O código funciona e não retorna erros no prompt, porém ele só escreve "None" no arquivo. E se repetir 3 vezes, aparece 3 vezes None (NoneNoneNone).

Esse é um exemplo do código:

```
import random

with open('texto.txt','a') as f:
    print('Para finalizar, digite "fim"')
    while True:
    
        escolha1 = input("escolha uma letra: ")
        if escolha1 == "fim":
            break
        escolha2 = input("escolha de novo: ")
    
        texto1 = ["%s é uma letra diferente de %s"%(escolha1,escolha2),"os dois são diferentes","%s não parece com %s"%(escolha1,escolha2)]
        texto2 = ["os dois são iguais"," são mesma coisa","escolheu a mesma coisa"]

        if escolha1 != escolha2:
            q = str(random.choice(texto1))
            f.write(str(print('%s' % q)))

        else:
            w = str(random.choice(texto2))
            f.write(str(print('%s' % w)))

        continue
    
print("fim")
f.close()
```

Também já tentei usar `f = open("texto.txt", "a")` e com o `f.write` direto (`f.write(str(random.choice(texto)))`)

Comment: `f.write(str(print('%s' % q)))`, o que você está escrevendo no arquivo é o retorno da função `print`, que sempre será `None`. Se quer que seja escrito a frase no arquivo, faça apenas `f.write(q)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sobre o problema de apenas escrever `None` no seu arquivo é devido ao fato que no seu código o que você manda escrever é o retorno da função `print`, convertida para string.

```
f.write(str(print('%s' % q)))
```

A função `print` enviará o parâmetro passado para a saída padrão do sistema, `STDOUT`, e sempre retornará `None`. Ao usar a classe `str`, você cria a string `"None"`, que é escriva no arquivo. Se a intenção é escrever o valor de `q` no arquivo, basta fazer `f.write(q)`.

Sobre o restante do seu código, eu sugeriria fazer algo como:

```
import random

# Evite nomear variáveis apenas com uma letra, pode não ficar legível o suficiente
with open('texto.txt','a') as stream:

    print('Para finalizar, digite "fim"')

    while True:
    
        escolha1 = input("escolha uma letra: ")
        if escolha1 == "fim":
            break

        escolha2 = input("escolha de novo: ")
        # Permite o usuário finalizar o programa na segunda opção também
        if escolha2 == "fim":
            break
    
        # Nomes de variáveis sugestivos com o seu propósito
        # Prefira utilizar as f-strings para a interpolação de strings no lugar de %
        textos_letras_diferentes = [
            f"{escolha1} é uma letra diferente de {escolha2}",
            "os dois são diferentes",
            f"{escolha1} não parece com {escolha2}"
        ]

        textos_letras_iguais = [
            "os dois são iguais",
            "são mesma coisa",
            "escolheu a mesma coisa"
        ]

        # Para escrever no arquivo, a única coisa que muda é a lista de frases, então...
        textos = textos_letras_diferentes if escolha1 != escolha2 else textos_letras_iguais 

        # Não precisa converter para str aquilo que já é string
        texto = random.choice(textos)
        stream.write(texto)

        # Não precisa utilizar o "continue" no final do laço
    
print("fim")

# Não precisa fechar o arquivo explicitamente, o "with" fará isso para você
```